# How to apply Zorn's Lemma on open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Every chain in the open interval $(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}$ has an upper bound, but $(0,1)$ has not a maximal. I use the $<$ as the usual meaning "the less than ordering".

What happened in this example since it contradicts Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: Why don't you show us the proof of your first sentence?

Comment: What is "a maximal"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\{1-\frac 1 n\}$ is a chain in $(0,1)$ with no upper bound. Zorn's Lemma does not apply.